# Finding a basis of a subspace of a cartesian product of two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $$T=\lbrace \left((a,b,c),\left[\begin{matrix} x & y \\\ y & z \end{matrix}\right] \right)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}:a+b+c=0 \wedge y=x+z\rbrace$$

$\times$ is cartesian product.

Find a basis and the dimension of $T$.

What I did:
Using the conditions $c=-a-b$ and $y=x+z$ we get

$T=\lbrace \left((a,b,-a-b),\begin{bmatrix} x & x+z \\\ x+z & z \end{bmatrix}\right):a,b,x,z \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$

$T=\lbrace \left(a(1,0,-1)+b(0,1,-1),x\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + z\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right):a,b,x,z \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$

$T=\lbrace (a(1,0,-1),x\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix})+(b(0,1,-1),z\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}):a,b,x,z \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$

At this point, I don't know how to take vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ that span $T$. (Must be at most 7 vectors because $dim(\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2})=7$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you could take the sequence of vectors:

$$v_1=[(1,0,-1),\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}]$$
$$v_2=[(0,1,-1),\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}]$$
$$v_3=[(0,0,0),\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}]$$
$$v_4=[(0,0,0),\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}]$$

Treating the two parts of the cartesian product as individual parts if you will.

This is linearly independent (Trivial but proof left to you) and spanning, as any element of the form above can be made by this sequence of vectors: For example , if I wanted to make $$[(a,b,-a-b),\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}]$$, I could take $av_1+bv_2 $ I leave the more general case of the spanning property for you to prove.

Thus the size of the basis is 4 as this is an LI spanning sequence. Thus, the dimension is 4.

As an aside: You could see this as a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R^4}$ ( you can set $c=-a-b$ and $y=x+z$ ) to a space of dimension 7. And the kernel of that transformation has a dimension of zero (as the only vector which undergoing the transformation will result in the zero vector is $a=0, b=0, x=0, z=0$) , so by the rank nullity theorem, the dimension of the image of the transformation must be 4 (as $dim kerT+ dimimT= dim\mathbb{R^4}=4$)

Comment: Thanks, I've just proved those 4 vectors are linearly independent and span $T$ so they form a basis indeed. Haven't thought about treating $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ as individual parts...